# How can you argue for a classification without assuming the classification?

Tags: epistemology, classification

Assume population x differs from population y by characteristic z. One group of scholars argues that x and y belong to the same class and that z is incidental and irrelevant to the classification. Another group takes the opposite view: that x and y belong to distinct classes because of z. Is there a way to decide between these two positions?

Comment: Does such a classification serve some other purpose?

Comment: If there's a distinguishing feature it can be used to classify. I can't see how any such classification could be invalid, even though it might be more distracting than useful.

Comment: No, there is nothing to resolve. Without extra criteria, like a purpose, they are just talking about two different classifications that may both be useful for different purposes.